# Locating points along line using distance table in QGIS

Tags: point, geolocation

I have a table of observations along a line (Road), with a distance of each observation point from start or from the last observation. I am looking for a method to locate the points from the table using the distance field (From the start point of the road). The table has the distance parameters from the start, but no coordinates (Only for the road start).

How do I do this using QGIS?

Comment: In QGIS you can use the ["Interpolate point on line"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisinterpolatepoint) tool from the Processing Toolbox. For *Distance* choose the distance field. Be careful with the CRS

Comment: If this is a recurring task you should look at linear referencing, there are several QGIS plugin dedicated to the task

Comment: If you wish to also ask about ArcGIS Pro then please do that in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Geoemtry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#hard-fa-geometry-generator-symbology) for visualization only or [Geometry by Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) for actual geometries ([see here for differences](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392618/use-qgis-expressions-to-create-geometries-difference-between-geometry-generator/392619#392619)) with this expression, where you have to replace `distances` by the name of the *layer* and `dist` with those of the *fieldname* containing the distance values:

```
collect_geometries(
    array_filter(
        array_foreach(
            aggregate( 'distances', 'array_agg',dist),
            line_interpolate_point( $geometry, @element)
        ),
        @element is not NULL
    )
)
```

*Points (red) created on the line at distances from the line's start point according to the values in the attribute field `dist` from layer `distances`:*
[image]

Remark: Geometry by Expression returns a multipart geometry with all point in one feature. Run [Multipart to single parts](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgismultiparttosingleparts) to get a separate feature for each point.